# Adding a CM User from External System to Sitecore

Tags: user-management, membership-provider, identity

I am using Sitecore `10.1`, there is a business requirements to allow external system to add CM users to Sitecore so my question is:

- Is there an `API` that we can access to add the `users` in Sitecore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a custom API will work for you. Where you can write this logic to create user into Sitecore database. Here is a code snippet that you can refer to.

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(domain\user, "password", "some@example.com");
```

For example

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(@"sitecore\myuser", "b", "myuser@sample.com");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore provides [RESTful APIs](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html) for `Item` manipulation but there is NO native API to create user in Sitecore.

You will need custom API for same.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore uses the standard `ASP.NET Membership` provider for its users so you can create users with custom API calls.

```
userName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain, userName);
Membership.CreateUser(userName, password, email);
```

You can create your custom API using this code sample.
[Programmatically Add/Edit Users](https://sitecorecodesamples.blogspot.com/2010/11/programmatically-addedit-users.html)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I encountered a similar necessity, wherein an external system required the creation of users within Sitecore. To address this, I developed an API facilitating the seamless creation of users from the external system directly into Sitecore.

This is a code which you can use:

```
string userNameWithDomain = "extranet\\myuser";
string password = "somepassword";
string email = "myuser@somewhere.com";
Membership.CreateUser(userNameWithDomain, password, email);
```